# Why did I fail an audit for a question that asked 5 questions in one?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, flags, review-audits

I was reviewing some questions in the [Triage review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and came across this review task:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/32665526

As you can easily see, this question asked 5 questions. The user wanted help setting the correct values for these:

```
Append
IsReady
SetReady
WakeUp (talking about the exchange)
Remove
```

... and then there were 2 more extra questions.

I immediately flagged it as needing more focus, and got the warning to "Stop and Listen...", plus got suspended from reviewing for 4 weeks.

Can you clarify why I was wrong to flag this question as needing more focus?

Comment: I'd argue that setting the correct value for those 5 is _1_ question. I certainly wouldn't recommend reposting the same question 5 times, ones for each function...

Comment: If you got suspended for several weeks (not sure why 3, though, unless it was a manual suspension), it is likely that you had previous review suspensions (as the "penalty" gets progressively bigger automatically) [which isn't surprizing in the Triage queue]. More on point, the audit doesn't seem like a bad one - despite having 6 "questions", it is focused on one problem only (Makoto already mentioned it in their answer).

Comment: This is the most difficult question I have seen in weeks, it took me several re-reads just to get the gist of what the OP is trying to solve and why - I still don't fully get it. How can you with a straight face claim "As you can easily see". No. Quite the opposite. Unless you hip fire because it contains a numbered list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe another way to think of this:  if this really *was* five distinct questions in one, then what are they and how could they be expressed on the site?

If you're struggling to split them up from there, then it's likely *not* multiple questions in one.

I'm not seeing this as five questions; I'm seeing this as one question with five tightly related components to it.  I'm not a C++ programmer by any stretch of the imagination though, so maybe some C++ expert would come along and disagree with my assessment, which would be totally fine.

Comment: From the C++ end, I agree - there's no useful way to consider each sub-question in isolation, because the problem is how they all synchronize with each other.

Comment: I'd say look at the other way in the sense something that is one question is something that is **likely*** to be well served by one clear. The asker makes the reasonable proposal that 4 of the 5 cases have the same answer and I'm not sure what the other 2 questions are but if they're the (right?) in brackets surely that's part of the same question. People close questions because the asker hasn't tried themselves and then they're getting closed for offering ideas. There is no useful absolute answer to "what is one question?".

Comment: "People close questions because the asker hasn't tried themselves" Yes, well, this is often misguided. I've said a few times on Meta now, OP including half-baked attempts at the problem in the question often makes the question *worse*.